# Is there any way to make GetForegroundwindow() to fire a callback function when the window update in python with pywin32?

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I'm learning how to work with the win32 api's and my initial plan is to build something like a companion app(like a bonzi buddy) but that it tracks/interacts with windows and more.

To learn the basics I'm using python with the piwin32 library to help me to understand the basics before moving it to C++.

One of my problems is when using the GetForegroundwindow() on python, because it doesn't have a callback function I'm run it inside an infinite loop for now. Is there a way for me to setup a callback function that only runs when it updates?

Answer (score 3):

[`SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook)